# How can I mount an external USB pen connected to Ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, usb-drive

USB sticks don't automount when connected to my Ubuntu phone Bq Aquaris e5. And in terminal app "lsusb" is not even present
Any idea on how to see, mount and access external USB storage connected trough USB port?

Answer (score 0):

I bought a micro USB-USB adapter and tried with different sticks on my bq 4.5. It mounts automatically and can be found on "Places" (swipe from bottom on File Manager). Sometimes it fails to show there, but it can be found in /home/media/phablet. Not all sticks work, but I suppose it depends on the power consumption of the stick. I get it work with a dual usb-lightning stick. Sometimes it disconnects but I guess it is due to the cheap adapter.